# Python Dictionary Counts

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp

I am trying to obtain the number of counts from a dictionary. I currently have the results out put as this :

```
 'HOVERED': dict_values([1]),
 'SCOUNDREL': dict_values([1, 1]),
 'SOLDIER': dict_values([1]),
 'WHIM': dict_values([1]),
 'WHISPER': dict_values([1]),
 'STORE': dict_values([1]),
 'SWORD': dict_values([1, 1, 1, 1]),
```

etc...

The data is of the form `trigram_smoothed_counts[i] = value2.values()`
I am trying to extract the number of counts from the list below (there are over 5000 items)
in form:

```
     'HOVERED': 1,
     'SCOUNDREL': 2,
     'SOLDIER': 1,
     'WHIM': 1,
     'WHISPER': 1,
     'STORE': 1,
     'SWORD': 4,
```

I have tried

```
trigram_smoothed_counts[i] = list(value2.values())[0]
```

which just brings out the first value in the "values" column of the dictionary.

How do I extract the sum of the values from dict_values?

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps `sum(value2.values())`? It's hard to make a better suggestion, because the code that you have posted is not valid python code, so I have a hard time understanding exactly how your data is stored. I am guessing ` 'SCOUNDREL': dict_values([1, 1]),` is not written like this in your code?

Comment: Please show the Python code you're having trouble with

Comment: I workedout the solutions. simply : `trigram_smoothed_counts[i] = len(trigram_counts[i])`